# python:type error while connection

Tags: python, mysql, sql

[image]
I just got a error over this code like

```
    if rows[0] in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

my Code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT student FROM myclass")
rows=cursor.fetchall() 


with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for row in rows:
            if rows[0] in line:
               stmt="select english from marks where student = :student"
               cursor.execute(stmt,dict(student=row[0]))
               print "english marks:",cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
```

please help,since it doesnot provide me any output with no errors

Answer (score 1):

You are using `rows[0]` where you probably meant to use `row[0]` instead:

```
for row in rows:
    if row[0] in line:
```

`rows` is a list of tuples, so `rows[0]` is the first such tuple. `row[0]` is the first column in the current row (e.g. the `student` column from the `SELECT`).

Comment: ya but not i dont det the oupput,its just displays with no errors!

Comment: @user3647415: so there is no line in your file with those values in them? What type is that column?

Comment: i will just provide u an image consisting of the textfile,and 2 mysql tables,have a look and help me!